# Как правильно сверстать такое расписание?

Tags: вёрстка

[image: Собственно вот]

что бы не делал, ползает всяко либо съезжает(

Comment: Приложите свой вариант реализации. Вам помогут найти и исправить ошибки и недочёты.

Answer (score 3):

При помощи простых таблиц

```css
.date {
color:gray;
text-align:right;
}
.time {
color:#1A7E91;
}
.time sup {
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
<table border="0" style="text-transform:uppercase; font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;">
  <tr>
    <td class="date">Понедельник - Четверг</td>
    <td class="time">9 <sup>00</sup> до 18 <sup>00</sup></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="date">Пятница</td>
    <td class="time">9 <sup>00</sup> до 18 <sup>00</sup></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block"><span class="grey">Понедельник - Четверг: </span><span class="date">9 <sup>00</sup> до 18 <sup>00</sup></span></div>
  <div class="block right"><span class="grey">Пятница: </span><span class="date">9 <sup>00</sup> до 17 <sup>00</sup></span></div>
</div>
<style>
  .block {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    /*ширина блока*/
  }
  
  .grey {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: grey;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  
  .date {
    color: blue;
  }
  
  .date sup {
    text-decoration: underline;
    /*подчеркивание 00*/
  }
  
  .right {
    text-align: right;
    /*выравниваем по правой стороне*/
  }
</style>
```

Comment: запустите и посмотрите, сползает